# Why do I have an alarm symbol on my notification bar when I don't have an alarm set

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons, alarm

I recently started seeing the alarm icon on my notification bar even though I don't have an alarm set.

Why is this happening? What can I do to find what's making this show? I don't want to disable the icon since I want it show when I do have an alarm set.

[image: This image shows the icon I'm referring to]

Comment: Do you have Tasker installed?

Comment: Yes I have it installed.

Answer (score 2):

When you enable Tasker it starts showing an alarm icon in the status bar. there is a setting in Tasker that is the culprit for this.
"Preferences -> Monitor -> Use Reliable Alarms" when set to always on it puts the icon there. Set it to When Off and the icon goes away.

See [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/632igt/permanent_alarm_icon_in_status_bar_on_android_it/)